# How can I store list map object in share preference in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary

I have a list of map and I want to store in share preference.How can I do that.Any example?I share my list of map.

```html
playlist = [{'id':1,
             'album':'Test',
             'url':''},
             {'id':2,
             'album':'Test',
             'url':''}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `save` a **List** in **SharedPreference** you can simply `encode` it to `json` by doing so it will be converted to string and after using `setString` function you can save that in `Shared Preference` and `decode` it back when getting from Shared Preference. Like below :

```
List list = ["abc","bcd","efg"];

final jsonData = jsonEncode(list);

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString("mykey", jsonData);

print(prefs.getString("mykey")); // to print json data
final List list1 = jsonDecode(prefs.getString("mykey").toString());
print(list1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to know is normal list and map list will be the same for saving in share preference.

Comment: Yes There will be no change in your data just you need to decode it before using. Also mark as answer if it worked for you. Thanks